# sqlalchemy: migrate data from mysql to sqlite failes, Index "ClassName" already exists

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I try to create a local SQLITE "working" copy of my live MYSQL database for better performance.

I got the type conversion for MYSQL->SQLITE types working, but now the migration fails during the index creation with the following exception:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) index ClassName already exists [SQL: u'CREATE INDEX "ClassName" ON "Member" ("ClassName")']

where "ClassName" is a column name. The full output of the engine can be found here: http://pastebin.com/zPUQikvs

I think the problem is that the same index name is reused, but I don't know how to change this.

I use the following script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, sys
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import ENUM, MEDIUMTEXT, TINYINT


# Define MySQL -> SqLite mappings
@compiles(ENUM, 'sqlite')
def compile_ENUM(element, compiler, **kw):
    """ Handles mysql ENUM type as String in sqlite"""
    return compiler.visit_string(element, **kw)


# Define MySQL -> SqLite mappings
@compiles(MEDIUMTEXT, 'sqlite')
def compile_MEDIUMTEXT(element, compiler, **kw):
    """ Handles mysql MEDIUMTEXT type as String in sqlite"""
    return compiler.visit_string(element, **kw)


# Define MySQL -> SqLite mappings
@compiles(TINYINT, 'sqlite')
def compile_TINYINT(element, compiler, **kw):
    """ Handles mysql TINYINT type as String in sqlite"""
    return compiler.visit_integer(element, **kw)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Fix import
    pwd = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
    sys.path.append(pwd)

    import legacy_config as cfg

    src = sa.create_engine(cfg.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
    dst = sa.create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)

    # Create Meta and reflect Source DB
    meta = sa.MetaData()
    meta.reflect(bind=src)

    meta.create_all(bind=dst)
```

Comment: " try to create a local SQLITE "working" copy of my live MYSQL database for better performance" these two databasea are vastly different. The local development copy should also be mysql.  " got the type conversion for MYSQL->SQLITE types working" sqlite doesn't even have types!

Comment: Why the downvote? I never said that it's for further developement of the live database. The local database is only used for data analysis where a speedup is nice. And sqlite has types: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html